# Subject Alternative Name in keystore for docker containers with dynamic IP

Tags: docker, ssl, ip, tls1.2, keytool

We are facing an issue while specifying Subject Alternative names in keystores for jetty 9.4.18. Since we are using docker containers with dynamic IP, IP cannot be used as SAN, nor can domain name.

Need help with this, preferably an example format of SAN for a Keystore when DNS or IP is not available.

We have tried using a common name, which is also not working. Nor is ip:"0.0.0.0" working for the container.

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias "alias" -keyalg "key_alg"  -keysize "key_size" keystore "keystore_path" -ext san=dns:host_name,ip:ip_address
```

or

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias "alias" -keyalg "key_alg"  -keysize "key_size" keystore "keystore_path" -ext san="ip_address"
```

or

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias "alias" -keyalg "key_alg"  -keysize "key_size" keystore "keystore_path" -ext san=cn:"common_name"
```

None of this is working.

Errors are thrown either during the generation of Keystore, or SSL related errors 
 during running of the application in the Docker container.

Comment: Are these containers running on aws. If so then try using aws ec2 private dns `*.eu-west-1.compute.internal`

Comment: @mchawre Thank you for the help. Keytool does not seem to allow wildcard characters while creating keystores. Could you please suggest a keystore creation tool which allows wildcards ?  Also had a query , how would we specify the SAN if we are using local docker containers ?

Comment: In this command `keytool -genkeypair -alias "alias" -keyalg "key_alg"  -keysize "key_size" keystore "keystore_path" -ext san=dns:host_name,ip:ip_address
` try to change `host_name` to `ip-172-x-x-x.eu-west-1.compute.internal` (exact private/public dns of that ec2 machine)

Comment: THE common name CN of the certificate should be `*.eu-west-1.compute.internal`

Comment: "IP cannot be used as SAN"  IP addresses can completely be used in SAN extension, you just need to use a type of "IPAddress" instead of "DNSname". This is rare, but possible. More difficult to get a CA sign it obviously, but no problem for internal certificates.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek IP cannot be used as SAN since the IP address of the docker container is dynamic and hence not known beforehand.

Comment: I am facing this very same problem. Any solution to that? Is create the certificate on the container initialization a solution to this problem?